# MVC manipulate URL (routing), is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website that use this pattern.

http://www.domain.com/product/...

My question is now, i need to create a subsite that going to be with this URL pattern, i have tried to change the routing without success.

http://www.domain.com/companyname/product/...

How can i inject the companyname in the URL without breaking my current routing?

Thanks
Niden

Comment: Are you talking about [Areas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC)?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Should `/companyname/product` request be routed to the same controller/method as `/product` or should it be another one? Will companyname be some static text or should it be somehow dynamic?

Comment: if you want a new website under a subfolder, you should create a virtual directory and publish your new website in it.

Comment: /companyname/product request should use the same controller/methods as /product. The companyname is kinda static text.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways:

1. If it's relatively static, you can follow Andy's advice in the comments and publish the site in a virtual directory, `companyname`. Assuming you've properly used the `UrlHelper` extensions to generate URLs, instead of just hard-coding paths, then everything will just work.
2. You can create a "companyname" area. The default routing for an area is `/area/controller/action`. So that would get you the URL structure you want. However, areas are somewhat segregated, so you would need to copy controllers and views to the area's directory. Although, you could subclass controllers from the main app in the area to reuse code.
3. Just change the default route/add a new route:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       "CompanyDefault",  
       "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
   );

   // default route here
   ```